# Vue.js Bootstrap Modal is closed on ok()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning Vue.js and developing a Web application at the same time. I am new to Vue.js and just started yesterday. Now, I am having trouble with the bootstrap modal. The problem is the modal is closed when I click on the ok button. I tried solution of using preventDefault. But it is not working as well.

This is my code.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <!-- Modal Component -->
        <b-modal title="Tell us a little about yourself, please." v-model="isLoginModalOpen" @ok="submitForm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <b-form-fieldset label="Name">
                        <b-form-input type="text" id="name" v-model="name" placeholder="Enter your name"></b-form-input>
                    </b-form-fieldset>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.row-->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <b-form-fieldset label="Email">
                        <b-form-input type="text" v-model="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email"></b-form-input>
                    </b-form-fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </b-modal>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Form from '../models/Form';
    export default {
        name : "login",
        data : function (){
            return {
                isLoginModalOpen : true,
                name : "",
                email : ""
            }
        },
        methods: {
            submitForm(evt){
                evt.preventDefault()
                alert('Submit form')
            }
        },
        mounted() {

        }
    }
</script>
```

If I clicked the OK button, the modal is closed even if I prevented the default behaviour. How can I fix it?

Comment: I prepared jsfiddle with your code but modal is not closed on Ok button and works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/maxsinev/bofh9aaa/60/

Comment: Wrong way to learn. You should learn one thing at a time otherwise you will have to spent more time it would take to learn them separately.